# fullcalendar event info in modal popup

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-4

I am working on fullCalendar and attempting to get the event info to show in a popup modal (when the event is clicked on).

However I can only get the event title, location, start date and end date showing.

I also need the start time and end time showing. What am I doing wrong?

My code is below:

```
eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    var startdate= new Date(event.event.start);
    var enddate= new Date(event.event.end);
    var starttime= new Date(event.event.startTime);
    var endtime= new Date(event.event.endTime);
    //console.log(event);
    $('#modalID').html(event.event.id);
    $('#modalTitle').html(event.event.title);
    $('#modalLocation').html(event.event.extendedProps.location);
    $('#modalStartDate').html(moment(startdate.getTime()).format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
    $('#modalStartTime').html(moment(starttime.getTime()).format("hh:mm A"));

    //moment("01:15:00 PM", "h:mm:ss A").format("HH:mm:ss")

    $('#modalEndDate').html(moment(enddate.getTime()).format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
    $('#modalEndTime').html(moment(endtime.getTime()).format("hh:mm A"));
    $('#fullCalModal').modal();
},
```

My updated code is below

```
 <script>

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

 var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

 plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid' ],
 defaultDate: '<cms:date format='Y-m-d' />',
 editable: true,
 eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
 displayEventTime: false,

 events: [
 <cms:pages masterpage='events.php' show_future_entries='1'>
    {
 id: <cms:escape_json><cms:show k_page_id /></cms:escape_json>, 
 title: <cms:escape_json><cms:show k_page_title /></cms:escape_json>,
 location: <cms:escape_json><cms:show location /></cms:escape_json>,
 start: <cms:escape_json><cms:show start_date /></cms:escape_json>,
 startTime: <cms:escape_json><cms:show start_time /></cms:escape_json>,
 end: <cms:escape_json><cms:show end_date /></cms:escape_json>,
 endTime: <cms:escape_json><cms:show end_time /></cms:escape_json>
}<cms:if "<cms:not k_paginated_bottom/>">,</cms:if>
</cms:pages>
],
eventClick: function(info) {

var dateSettings = { "year": "numeric", "month": "2-digit", "day": "2-digit" 
};
var timeSettings = { "hour": "2-digit", "minute": "2-digit", "hour12": false 
};

var startdate = calendar.formatDate(info.event.start,  dateSettings);
var startTime = calendar.formatDate(info.event.start,  timeSettings);

var enddate = calendar.formatDate(info.event.end || startdate, 
dateSettings);
var endTime = calendar.formatDate(info.event.end, timeSettings);

$('#modalID').html(info.event.id);
$('#modalTitle').html(info.event.title);
$('#modalLocation').html(info.event.extendedProps.location);
$('#modalStartDate').html(startdate);
$('#modalStartTime').html(startTime);
$('#modalEndDate').html(enddate);
$('#modalEndTime').html(endTime);
$('#fullCalModal').modal();
},

eventTextColor: '#FFFFFF',

});

calendar.render();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are really tying yourself in knots here.

1) As per [the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) `event.start` and `event.end` are already Date objects. There is really no need to parse them into another Date or make them into MomentJS objects again. Just use them as they already are, and format them as needed using fullCalendar's provided [date formatting functionality](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-library).

2) The event object (again see docs above) does not have a separate "startTime" or "endTime" property...the whole date and time is stored within `start` and `end`. I'm not sure where you got the idea that separate properties exist? This has never been the case in any version of fullCalendar.

3) You need to deal with the case where the event's `end` property might be null, so there's a little bit of extra logic to handle that, and just use the start date/time instead:

```
eventClick: function(info) {
  var dateSettings = { "year": "numeric", "month": "2-digit", "day": "2-digit" };
  var timeSettings = { "hour": "2-digit", "minute": "2-digit", "hour12": false };

  var startdate = calendar.formatDate(info.event.start,  dateSettings);
  var starttime = calendar.formatDate(info.event.start,  timeSettings);

  var enddate; 
  var endtime; 
  if (info.event.end != null) {
    enddate = calendar.formatDate(info.event.end, timeSettings );
    endtime = calendar.formatDate(info.event.end, dateSettings );
  } 
  else {
    enddate = startdate;
    endtime = starttime;
  }

  $('#modalID').html(info.event.id);
  $('#modalTitle').html(info.event.title);
  $('#modalLocation').html(info.event.extendedProps.location);
  $('#modalStartDate').html(startdate);
  $('#modalStartTime').html(starttime);
  $('#modalEndDate').html(enddate);
  $('#modalEndTime').html(endtime);
  $('#fullCalModal').modal();
},
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eapjWN?editors=1010

N.B. If, as it appears, you are using fullCalendar v4, then your callback arguments for eventClick are wrong - again see the relevant [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) - yours look like the v3 arguments. `jsEvent` and `view` are no longer supplied separately, instead they are supplied within the info object which is now the first argument. And talking of that, calling the first argument `event` is really a misnomer, since it contains more than that. The fact you've ended up writing `event.event...` tells you you've got a naming problem. Better to name it more meaningfully. In the interest of code quality, my example above makes those changes in addition to the ones necessary to solve the actual problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193064/discussion-on-answer-by-adyson-fullcalendar-event-info-in-modal-popup).

Comment: @IanHaney (following on from the discussion now moved to comments)...if you want the date in a culture-specific format, then set the "locale" of the calendar. This will control the formatting of dates and other culture-specific displays in the calendar. e.g. here's my CodePen updated to use the UK English locale - this produces the times in dd/mm/yyyy format: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYVVvb?editors=1010. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale for more information.

Comment: @IanHaney and regarding the times...you need to start adding the time value into the `start` and `end` properties of your events.

Comment: Based on the sample event data I could see by looking in the View Source display of your web page, you should be aiming for event data which looks like this: `[{
  id: "163",
  title: "Test Event Two",
  location: "Test Location",
  start: "2019-05-07 09:00:00",
  end: "2019-05-07 10:00:00",
}, {
  id: "162",
  title: "Test Event Three",
  location: "Test Location",
  start: "2019-05-06 09:00:00",
  end: "2019-05-09 16:00:00",
}, {
  id: "161",
  title: "Test Event",
  location: "Test Location",
  start: "2019-05-04 09:00:00",
  end: "2019-05-04 10:30:00",
}]`

Comment: I'm not familiar with your CMS functions, but to achieve that I would guess you need to write something like `start: <cms:escape_json><cms:show start_date /> <cms:show start_time /></cms:escape_json>,
 end: <cms:escape_json><cms:show end_date /> <cms:show end_time /></cms:escape_json>` so that both the date and time are combined into one value in the output

Comment: I have updated the coding bit it breaks the calendar, see https://pastebin.com/1cPZVQnh

in console I have the following

SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
note: [ opened at line 45, column 10

calendar.php:100:1

I looked around them lines and all match up so all I can think is that for some odd reason, there can't be two <cms: show /> in the same line which thought that would be ok

I commented out the starttime and endtime bits in the code as thought they would not be needed as putting the start date and start time together and same for end date and end time

Comment: Use the View Source display in your web browser to look at your page and see what the output looks like. Then you can check where the syntax error is.  Like I said, I don't know exactly what your CMS functions do, so maybe I got it wrong. Check what the output is, and then amend your CMS code accordingly till it produces the desired result. (Again...you need to be learning to debug JavaScript and web pages, then you can start to fix these kinds of problems yourself! It's a **vital** skill)

Comment: "I commented out the starttime and endtime bits in the code as thought they would not be needed"...correct, you don't need them. Instead of commenting them out, just remove them

Comment: I will try but quickly looking at the source code, the events output is the following

events: [
            {
     id: "163", 
     title: "Test Event Two",
     location: "Test Location",
     start: "2019-05-07 00:00:00 09:00",
     //starttime: "09:00",
     end: "2019-05-07 00:00:00 10:00",
     //endtime: "10:00"    }, ]

so maybe that's where it's getting broken as the start line is start: "2019-05-07 00:00:00 09:00", and end line is end: "2019-05-07 00:00:00 10:00",

Comment: I think you need to 1) remove the commented-out lines completely, and 2) make your CMS code so it does not print the "00:00:00" part from the date.

Comment: I have removed the commented out lines and I have formatted the date output in the couchcms tags and the output of the start and end look ok to me now and the calendar is now showing but now no events are being shown on the calendar

events: [
            {
     id: "163", 
     title: "Test Event Two",
     location: "Test Location",
     start: "07-05-2019 09:00",
     end: "07-05-2019 10:00",
    },
],

Comment: I see you fixed the time, but why did you also change the date format to dd-mm-yyyy? fullCalendar cannot understand that. Read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing to know what input formats are acceptable. Change it back to yyyy-mm-dd (as you were using before) and it'll work.

Comment: ahh ok makes sense why no events were showing, I have put it back to yyyy-mm-dd and got the events showing but can't click on them now to view the modal popup

Comment: "can't" means what? What is going wrong? It means that again you haven't tried to debug it, I guess? First step...check the console for errors. If there's nothing useful showing, then second step...use the debugger and/or some console.log commands to check whether the eventClick function is running, and what the values of the variables are, etc

Comment: P.S. I updated my CodePen to use the event data currently being used on your webpage and it works fine, all the events are clickable: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYVVvb?editors=1010

Comment: I see also in your site you removed the time fields in the modal, and removed the code to create the times from the eventClick. Fine...but then for no apparent reason you also changed the other code: `var startdate = calendar.formatDate(info.event.start);` ...this will fail because you have to supply some formatting options (as per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-formatDate) - did you read it??). You are getting a console error about it....which you really should have checked before you messaged me!

Comment: See my updated CodePen for a fixed version: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYVVvb?editors=1010. `var dateSettings = { "year": "numeric", "month": "2-digit", "day": "2-digit", "hour": "2-digit", "minute": "2-digit", "hour12": false };

      var startdate = calendar.formatDate(info.event.start, dateSettings);

      var enddate; 
      if (info.event.end != null) {
        enddate = calendar.formatDate(info.event.end, dateSettings );
      } 
      else {
       enddate = startdate;
      }` - I combined the date and time settings into one object, and use that to format the date

Comment: I know you're new to JS coding but you really have to start paying closer attention to the documentation, and to the code you're writing, and also get into the habit of checking for errors. Your browser has very powerful Developer Tools, they are there to help you, so please learn to use them. Chrome, Firefox and others have online tutorials and documentation about the tools. If you want to be a web developer, you need to learn. Otherwise you will never be able to fix these kinds of simple issues. Take the time to do it now, and you'll save yourself hours of trouble when coding.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is looking good and perfect, just one thing if possible, between the year and time, can it have the word at so it shows as 07/05/2019 at 10:00 instead of 07/05/2019, 10:00

I did look on Google but did not find a answer and tried adding in within the events output but just stopped the events showing

Comment: I think that's just what fullCalendar's function does. If you want more control over how it comes out then you'll have to [do as the documentation suggests](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting) and go back to using momentJS to format the date. I didn't know you wanted such an exact format. Or alternatively, do it manually: format the date twice using the separate dateSettings and timeSettings I have got in the answer above, and then join the two results together in a string with "at" in between them. Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmgPwL?editors=1010

Comment: P.S. If the answer has helped you, please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick mark next to the question so it turns green) and/or give it an upvote, to recognise the answer as a useful one. You should do that on all questions where someone gives you useful information which solves (or helps to solve) the problem

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help and replies, it's perfect now. I will start learning js more, it's not often I get asked to do any js or anything like this, think this is the first time to be honest but will start learning it just in case it comes up in the future and I can solve the issues myself and hours of trouble with issues

Thank you again for all your help and replies and time. I have upvoted all the very useful coding/comments